# Saved jpeg file from mjpeg stream not recognized by PIL in python

Tags: python, image, jpeg, python-imaging-library, mjpeg

I am trying to snatch a valid JPEG frame from a webcam's MJPEG stream. I successfully write it to disk and I can open it in a program like Infranview, but Python and other graphic programs don't see it as a valid JPEG file. I wrote this function that snarfs it and writes it to disk

```
def pull_frame(image_url,filename):
    flag = 0
    # open the url of the webcam stream
    try:
            f = urllib.urlopen(image_url)
    except IOError:
            print "uh oh"
    else:
            # kill first two lines
            try:
                    null = f.readline()
            except:
                    print "duh"
            null = f.readline()
            pop = f.readline()
            # this pulls the length of the content
            count = pop[16:] # length of content.
            print "Size Of Image:" + count
            # read just the amount of the length of content
            if int(count):
                    s = f.read(int(count))
                    flag = 1
                    # write it to a file name
                    p = file(filename,'wb')
                    p.write(s)
                    p.close()
```

So i'm getting broken JPEG's and I even tried a hamfisted workaround by trying to use FFMPEG to make a valid PNG from the broken jpegs, and it worked from the comamnd line but not from subprocess. Is there a way in python to pull this jpeg from the mjpeg steam with a proper jpeg header?

Here is a link to a camera1.jpg that is an example of saved data from this routine that isnt recognized and also has no thumbnail (although infraview can open it find as a jpg)
http://www.2shared.com/photo/OfZh2XeD/camera1.html

Comment: Can you include one such broken JPEG (or a link to it) ?

Comment: I added a link at 2shared.com - uploaded a broke version of the jpg i get from the webcam at the link edited above!

Comment: Just so people know - i did a terrible work around where I use FFMPEG to convert the terrible jpg with no header into a png that has a huge file size to work with :)

clunky kludge but working at the moment!

Comment: Is that file still available ? I cannot download it, host it somewhere else.